# Can I move a movie rental from my Apple TV to my iPad?

Tags: itunes, appletv

If I rent a movie on my Mac, I can move the rented movie to my iPad.

Can I do the same if I rent a movie directly on my AppleTV?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, no.  Apple does not allow this.

Comment: Correct. Reference: http://support.apple.com/kb/HT1498, under “Additional Information” near the bottom.

Comment: And if you rent it on your Mac, you can stream it to your AppleTV, so renting on the AppleTV seems best suited for movies you want to watch right then.

Answer (score 3):

Quote from Apple Support Pages:
"Movies rented on your Apple TV are not transferable to any other device and can only be viewed on your Apple TV."

If you have a iMac or Macbook at home, rent it through that computer, and then stream it to Apple TV for watching there... Movies rented on that Apple computer can be transferred with a click over to your iPad.

Comment: Barnyard B.S. but thanks for the confirmation.